Header and Footer in TYPO3 how insert
I need to insert government code in the header and footer in TYPO3, but I can't find out if it is on the Default Template or if it is done in the constants, could someone help me?
I want to insert about the header and footer of my site to set javascript code.

I think you are looking for that: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Page/Index.html#confval-page-includejsfooterlibs or maybe: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Page/Index.html#confval-page-includejslibs

Or maybe this is better:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Page/Index.html#example-include-javascript-in-the-header

as TYPO3 is very flexible, there are a lot of possibilities where something can be defined. Therefore you need to analyse in which way your header and footer are defined to modify it. On the other hand TYPO3 has some Options to insert javascript in defined ways. Starting with TypoScript (includeJS/includeJSFooter/includeJSFooterlibs/includeJSLibs) to FLUID: f:asset.script

To get better answers you need at least to include the TypoScript setup of your page in the question.
